# Why has "open" from the right click menu stopped working?

Tags: windows-server-2003, context-menu

From three days ago when i want to open more than 1 files with "open" in right click,nothing will happen,but if i press enter  button all of selected files are open!

I  tried it with PDF,word & excel files, and the result was similar.It is necessary to say that for 1 file "open" is working but for more than 1 file not.

The last software that i installed is: spy-bot and for 1 week after that all things was nice but from 3 days ago i have this problem:-(

I am using Windows Server 2003r2, eset antivirus node 32 endpoint and have 6 GB of RAM.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: First step restore a system image from before when it worked.

Comment: thanks but i can't do it,it's a risk for me.Can i have another opinions of you?thanks so mush...